# How do I pass an array of configurations to a YAML file in Golang?

Tags: go, yaml

I am trying to create a YAML configuration file using [gosexy/yaml](https://github.com/gosexy/yaml).

I know how to create a YAML file of the following format:

```
another:
  tree:
  - 1
```

I use the code `settings.Set("another","tree",[]int{1})` to create the above file.

Now, how can I create a file of the format

```
another:
  - tree: 1
```

I tried using the code `settings.Set("another",[]{yaml.Set("tree",1)})` to create the above file. As it might be obvious, I receive a type error since I am not passing the type to the array.

Am I on the right track? If yes, what should be the type to be passed. If no, what is the alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the type of tree that you need is ***[]map[string]int***

example code:

```
settings := yaml.New()
settings.Set("another", []map[string]int{{"tree": 1}})
settings.Write("test.yaml")
```

the result of ***test.yaml***

```
another:
- tree: 1
```

hope it help

Comment: It Does Help. Thank You So Much.